# Login form jQuery plugin does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin for login form and I have an issue with the 'Submit' button. My 'Submit' button click function never gets executed.

Here is my jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/c4jRx/1/

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.login = function (options) {
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.login.config, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var markup =  '<div>' +
                      '<form method="post" action="">' +    
                      '<table><tr><td><label>User Login</label></td></tr>' +
                      '<tr><td><input type="text" id="user_id" placeholder="Apple ID" required></td></tr>' +
                      '<tr><td><input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required></td></tr>' +
                      '<tr><td><input type="submit" id="authenticate" value="Login to your account"></td></tr>' +
                      '</table>' +
                      '</form>' +
                      '</div>';
        return $(this).html(markup);
    });
    $('#authenticate').click(function() {
        debugger;
        var user = $('#user_id').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        console.log("User: " + user + "Password: " + password);
    });        
};


$.fn.login.config = {
    // set values and custom functions
};

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modify your fiddle and attaching it over here. The actual problem was you have written click event in login function and after adding html you have written return statement so click event was not getting registered.  Here is the solution for that.

Put you click event in document.ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loginScreen').login();
          $('#authenticate').click(function() {
                    var user = $('#user_id').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        console.log("User: " + user + "Password: " + password);
    });     
        });
```

Here is your updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c4jRx/5/ Thanks

Comment: This works, but the problem is if the user wants to re-use the form plugin, he has to redefine the click function every time.